# Quiet hissing out of audio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

This is not a duplicate, from what I've found.

Basically, a very quiet (but very noticeable with nice headphones) white noise/hiss is emitted. I'm on the latest version 13. Here's what I've found:

1. alsamixer does nothing
2. When I MUTE the speakers, the sound goes away
3. The noise starts right before the gui to login appears on bootup.
4. When I unplug the machine, the white noise will stop unless I am playing something, in which case it will have white noise until a few seconds after the music stops, and it 'pops' off.
5. This didn't happen with Windows 8.
6. I believe it's been happening since the clean Ubuntu install.
7. Turning volume up/down doesn't affect white noise volume. Only muting completely eliminates.

Please help a guy out. :-( This is make-or-break for Ubuntu... I need my music!

Answer (score 0):

If this is a laptop, then check in your mixer (here, `xfce4-mixer`) that the `capture` volume isn't set to maximum (or too high). Also check that the `mic boost` channels are set at reasonable levels. Sometimes I get hissing on my laptop because of too high volume for the microphone channels.